# puppeter connection error with browser and redirect bypass

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this error:

```
   ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                      ^

Error: net::ERR_FAILED at https://www.margonem.pl/`
```

I would like for page 1 to go to the page without automatic redirection, and for page 2 to go to the page normally. I also want to make such a service that it is checked for both sides whether the page has loaded successfully, i.e. without errors, there is no about:blank and so that I can manipulate the navigation, and if it does not load, let it refresh the page until it loads.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function connectToBrowser() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    slowMo: 10,
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized'],
  });

  const [page1, page2] = await Promise.all([
    browser.newPage(),
    browser.newPage(),
  ]);

  await page1.setRequestInterception(true);

  page1.on('request', (request) => {
    if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.redirectChain().length !== 0) {
      request.abort();
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  });

  await page1.goto('https://www.margonem.pl/');

  await page2.goto('https://forum.margonem.pl/?task=forum&show=posts&id=515920');

  return { page1, page2, browser };
}

connectToBrowser();
```

Comment: There've been a couple questions dealing with navigating to this page from you. Could you provide context for what you're trying to achieve here to avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)? Thanks.